# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' eval()'d code on line 1

Tags: php, eval

Отправляю такой код через post ajax из frontEnd

```
 $red = $this->session->data["red"];
 return $red;
```

Принимаю на сервере и обрабатываю с помощью eval

```
$code = $this->request->post['code'];
$code = preg_replace('/^ *(<\?php|<\?)/mi', '', $code);

ob_start();

$result = eval($code);

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if ($result) {
    $output = $result;
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in ./../. : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Как сделать так, что бы он нормально обрабатывал PHP?
Ошибка с eval

> PS: Это opencart, объект $this объявлен снаружи

Answer (score 0):

Так как при отправке post, данные были

```
$red = $this-&gt;session-&gt;data['red'];
echo $red;
```

Для меня оказалось РЕШЕНИЕМ

```
$code = html_entity_decode($code);
```

Comment: я чисто уточнить, то есть вы в коде используете eval который приходит постом?

Comment: Да, это для консоли администратора, если что
Я отправляю php код, eval его выполняет и возвращает ответ